# Detect app killed and cleanup Firestore. Voice chat app made by Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, agora.io

I'm making a voice chat app using Flutter for iOS and Android. I use Firebase Firestore to keep active users in a chat room. When a user kills an app (by swiping up in app list), I have no way to detect it. So there is no chance to remove a user from Firestore `users` field. I'd like to keep a user in firestore while an app is background. How to successfully know when a user leaves an app? Btw, I'm using Agora RTC SDK for voice call. Thank you for reading.

Firestore has the below structure

```
chatRoom (collection)
  - docidA (document)
    - users: ["name1", "name2"] (Array field)
```

Source code:

```dart
class RoomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RoomPage({Key key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RoomPageState createState() => _RoomPageState();
}

class _RoomPageState extends State<RoomPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Join into a chat and add myself to firebase firestore users field
    addMyselfToFirestore("docidA", "name1");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {  // Unfortunately Not called when a user kills this app.
    super.dispose();
    removeMyselfFromFirestore("docidA", "name1");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {...}

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      // Unfortunately detached not called when a user kills the app
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        removeMyselfFromFirestore("docidA", "name1");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Flutter

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b1395592de (7 days ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

Comment: Can I check with you if agora supportS flutter 2.0.4? I saw in their documentation that they only support Flutter 1.0.0 or later (Flutter 2.x is not supported)

Comment: agora_rtc_engine: ^3.3.2, agora_rtm: ^0.9.14 work on 2.0.6.

Comment: also on 2.2.0
Flutter 2.2.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b22742018b (6 days ago) • 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
Engine • revision a9d88a4d18
Tools • Dart 2.13.0

Answer (score 1):

I found workaround. You can't do on your app. Let the backend detect disconnection to your app when it is killed. Now I integrate Firestore and Firebase real time database.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: very cool solution, too sad there seems like no proper solution being within the apps however.. ]:

Answer (score 0):

did you try using AppLifeCycleState?

You can try using the detached state over here specifically for your use case and then trigger your Firebase Firestore code. You can read more about App state over here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html

Comment: Thank you. As is in my code, it doesn't work. App can't fire any event when killed.

Comment: wow, you are the person who helped me many times on Agora Slack! Thank you